# google sheets api v4 Append row after specific row or move row to specific position

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to append a row after a specific row/range?
For example, I have a spreadsheet with 5 rows where in column A is written for row one "1", for row two "2" but in row three "4" and so on till row five "6".

Now I want to append a row to this table and I currently use this function:

```
let values = [
  [
    // Cell values ...
  ],
  // Additional rows ...
];
let resource = {
  values,
};
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
  valueInputOption,
  resource,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error.
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
  }
});
```

The row I want to append has in column A a "3" and I want the row appended after Row two.

But when I set the range to "A2:C2" it will only append it where the first empty row is; after row five.

Is there a way to append rows inbetween rows? If not, is it possible to move the appended row from bottom to the desired position?

PS: I don't want to order the rows by alphabet or number. I just use numbers to show what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must insert a row inbetween first and then [`update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) the values in that row or `append`. You can try [`InsertRangeRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertRangeRequest) or [`InsertDimension`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest)

#### Snippet:

```
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  spreadsheetId,
  resource: { 
    requests: [{
     "insertRange": {
        "range": {//Sheet1!A3
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 2,
          "endRowIndex": 3,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
         },
        "shiftDimension": "ROWS"
      }
    }]
  }
},(err,res)=>console.log(err ? err : res))
```

Comment: Is this snippet for inserting inbetween? if yes, can I just add values to the resource object here? And is "InsertRangeRequest" just a normal update but with the property "shiftDimensions"?

Comment: @Take Yes. No. No. InsertRange only inserts a blank range(say a blank row). You must add a update request after this.

Comment: Mh I tried it and I get this error: `Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "shift_dimension" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.` I copied your snippet just added a spreadsheetId. Doyou know why this don't work?

Comment: Edit (not really): Ok, I saw whats missing here. The request object need a "insertRange" object with range and shiftDimensions.
 BUT I get an error that sheet_id 0 cant be found. Where can I see what Id my sheet has?

Comment: @Take Missed the request name. Added it. SheetId can be found in the spreadsheet url. `#gid=[SHEET_ID]`